# How can I go from Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport to Chengdu Research Base of Giant Panda Breeding?

Tags: trains, china, sichuan

I'm planing to leave Singapore in Friday evening and land in to Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport Friday midnight. I would like to travel directly to the area of Chengdu Research Base of Giant Panda Breeding and stay in a hotel around there.

My question is, how can I go from Chengdu Shuangliu International Airport to Chengdu Research Base of Giant Panda Breeding in the night? Is it safe?

Comment: At least you can use a taxi and it is cheap on Singaporean standard. I just checked now (AM 3:15) on Baidu map and it showed about 114 RMB.

Answer (score 1):

When I travelled to Chengdu, we booked a guided tour and it included all transfers. It is like booking a taxi for the whole day plus the guide.